# Array map truncates original keys upon providing more than one array argument

Tags: php, arrays

The following code:

```
$array = array("key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2");
print_r(array_map(function($v) {return $v . $v;}, $array));
```

has the expected result:

```
Array
(
    [key1] => value1value1
    [key2] => value2value2
)
```

However, adding an arbitrary parallel array as an argument to array map seems to invoke unexpected behaviour:

```
$array = array("key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2");
$array2 = array(1, 2);
print_r(array_map(function($v, $v2) {return $v . $v;}, $array, $array2));
```

This results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => value1value1
    [1] => value2value2
)
```

As you can see, the array keys have been replaced by numerically indexed ones. Now this I find very annoying, because I don't intend to lose the $array's keys. Is there a simple way to iterate over parallel arrays (which does not involve the iterator class or giving the arrays equal keys)? One option could be to manually call `next()` like so:

```
$array = array("key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2");
$array2 = array(1, 2);
print_r(array_map(function($v) use ($array2) {
    $v2 = current($array2);
    next($array2);
    return $v . $v;
}, $array));
```

But it feels a little dirty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented behavior (http://php.net/array_map#example-4917 and one line above it)

Every solution would feel dirty, but I would use with just [`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine) and [`array_keys`](http://php.net/array_keys):

```
$array = array("key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2");
$array2 = array(1, 2);
$final = array_combine(
    array_keys($array),
    array_map(function($v, $v2) {return $v . $v;}, $array, $array2)
);
```

Comment: For my use case I already found a different, shorter and faster solution, but your reply answers the question.

Comment: @user2180613 You can edit your question or add your own answer and share your solution for future viewer.